# Get Fix from Magento repository to my project

Tags: magento2

I have a question. How can I download the changes in this hotfix: 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/1e78fe2e37af0012b7f60b29c658221b8ab8467b

Version Magento in my project is **2.1.2** and I have a problem with this exception:

> Configurable product "44583" does not have sub-products

So, How can I download only this fix to my repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [composer-patch](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches) to apply Magento fix. To use it, you can do the following steps:

1. Install composer patch:

   composer require cweagans/composer-patches
2. Download your patch [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/1e78fe2e37af0012b7f60b29c658221b8ab8467b.patch) and edit and split that patch to something like this:
   [image]
3. Open **your_magento_install_dir/composer.json** and edit "extra" node to apply your patch like this:

   ```
   "extra": {
   "magento-force": "override",
   "patches": {
     "magento/module-catalog": {
       "Fix: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5762": "patches/your_patch.patch"
     },
     "magento/module-configurable-product": {
       "Fix: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5762": "patches/your_patch.patch"
     },
   }
   ```

   }

I hope this will solve your problem

Thanks