# Magento2: Updating a line of code in core file

Tags: php, magento2, magento-2.3

Here is what I need:
In file vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule/Action/Discount/CartFixed.php there is a public function calculate 
I want to comment an If condition inside this function without modifying this core file.

if ($availableDiscountAmount > 0) {

I have created a preference inside a custom module but it is not working as expected. I really appreciate if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: This is probably the wrong way to apply a discount. It's been a while since I dived into Magento, but from what I remember you should be able to add discounts within your own module without interfering with the core. Could you please explain in more detail what it is you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi @Kodaloid, Thank you for your reply.
I am trying to accomplish a negative discount  as Fixed amount discount for whole cart.
As you can see here https://screenshots.firefox.com/4XPDOcQ2VHYWxgdj/demostore.work
I have added "-25" as Design fee.

I have made a module with preference it is working for a second when we go to Cart please see https://screenshots.firefox.com/haAJZmGaTgaX3Iog/demostore.work

But my problem is it automatically refresh after a second and it vanished after that, I believe first preference is calling but after that core file is calling.

Comment: In case you want to review it in action please visit here
https://demostore.work/Designer/custom-bar-mitzvah-bencher-75

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize Magento core file, you can use Preference or [Plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html). More detail here

In your case, you can use preference as the following steps:

1. In the di.xml you can add the reference config:

`<preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\CartFixed" type="Training\Test\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\CartFixed" />`

2. Create Training\Test\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\CartFixed.php:

   - @author Bach Lee 
     */

   namespace Training\Test\Model\Rule\Action\Discount;

   use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
   use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
   use Magento\SalesRule\Model\DeltaPriceRound;
   use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator;
   use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\DiscountFactory;

   class CartFixed extends \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\CartFixed
   {
       /**
        * @var string
        */
       private static $discountType = 'CartFixed';
       /**
        * @var DeltaPriceRound
        */
       private $deltaPriceRound;

   ```
   /**
    * @param Validator $validator
    * @param DataFactory $discountDataFactory
    * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
    * @param DeltaPriceRound $deltaPriceRound
    */
   public function __construct(
       Validator $validator,
       DataFactory $discountDataFactory,
       PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
       DeltaPriceRound $deltaPriceRound = null
   ) {
       $this->deltaPriceRound = $deltaPriceRound ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(DeltaPriceRound::class);

       parent::__construct($validator, $discountDataFactory, $priceCurrency, $deltaPriceRound);
   }

   /**
    * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $rule
    * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item
    * @param float $qty
    * @return \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\Data
    * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
    */
   public function calculate($rule, $item, $qty)
   {
       /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\Data $discountData */
       $discountData = $this->discountFactory->create();

       $ruleTotals = $this->validator->getRuleItemTotalsInfo($rule->getId());

       $quote = $item->getQuote();
       $address = $item->getAddress();

       $itemPrice = $this->validator->getItemPrice($item);
       $baseItemPrice = $this->validator->getItemBasePrice($item);
       $itemOriginalPrice = $this->validator->getItemOriginalPrice($item);
       $baseItemOriginalPrice = $this->validator->getItemBaseOriginalPrice($item);

       /**
        * prevent applying whole cart discount for every shipping order, but only for first order
        */
       if ($quote->getIsMultiShipping()) {
           $usedForAddressId = $this->getCartFixedRuleUsedForAddress($rule->getId());
           if ($usedForAddressId && $usedForAddressId != $address->getId()) {
               return $discountData;
           } else {
               $this->setCartFixedRuleUsedForAddress($rule->getId(), $address->getId());
           }
       }
       $cartRules = $address->getCartFixedRules();
       if (!isset($cartRules[$rule->getId()])) {
           $cartRules[$rule->getId()] = $rule->getDiscountAmount();
       }

       $availableDiscountAmount = (float)$cartRules[$rule->getId()];
       $discountType = self::$discountType . $rule->getId();

       $store = $quote->getStore();
       if ($ruleTotals['items_count'] <= 1) {
           $quoteAmount = $this->priceCurrency->convert($availableDiscountAmount, $store);
           $baseDiscountAmount = min($baseItemPrice * $qty, $availableDiscountAmount);
           $this->deltaPriceRound->reset($discountType);
       } else {
           $ratio = $baseItemPrice * $qty / $ruleTotals['base_items_price'];
           $maximumItemDiscount = $this->deltaPriceRound->round(
               $rule->getDiscountAmount() * $ratio,
               $discountType
           );

           $quoteAmount = $this->priceCurrency->convert($maximumItemDiscount, $store);

           $baseDiscountAmount = min($baseItemPrice * $qty, $maximumItemDiscount);
           $this->validator->decrementRuleItemTotalsCount($rule->getId());
       }

       $baseDiscountAmount = $this->priceCurrency->round($baseDiscountAmount);

       $availableDiscountAmount -= $baseDiscountAmount;
       $cartRules[$rule->getId()] = $availableDiscountAmount;
       if ($availableDiscountAmount <= 0) {
           $this->deltaPriceRound->reset($discountType);
       }

       $discountData->setAmount($this->priceCurrency->round(min($itemPrice * $qty, $quoteAmount)));
       $discountData->setBaseAmount($baseDiscountAmount);
       $discountData->setOriginalAmount(min($itemOriginalPrice * $qty, $quoteAmount));
       $discountData->setBaseOriginalAmount($this->priceCurrency->round($baseItemOriginalPrice));
       $address->setCartFixedRules($cartRules);

       return $discountData;
   }
   ```

   }

Or you can use [cweagans/composer-patches](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches) following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602875/get-fix-from-magento-repository-to-my-project/53605178#53605178) to edit core Magento files

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

> code/Magento/* any name or module you need from core file 
>   If you need some more details let me know it is just like Magento 1 but only folder is changed

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Naseem
Till date I think it is not possible can you please show me how to make it work?
I am trying to edit/override this core file
vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule/Action/Discount/CartFixed.php

Answer (score 0):

App/Code/Magento/SalesRule/model/ *

Please use it like this

Answer (score 0):

After adding this please use compile command

Answer (score 0):

It works for me it will work for you also

First add folders 
App/Code/Magento/SalesRule/model/folder/file.php

And thank use "setup:upgrade" to update the files.
Than command "setup:di:compile".

Regards 
Naseem